# TYPO3 Backend: AJAX with jQuery (params empty)

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

According to the Backend API: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/JavaScript/Ajax/Backend/Index.html I could use every library to do AJAX calls in the TYPO3 Backend.

I get the success message, but my params array is always empty:

**Controller**

```
public function renderShowModal($params = array(), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AjaxRequestHandler &$ajaxObj = NULL){
    var_dump($params);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: TYPO3.settings.ajaxUrls['Controller::renderShowModal'],
            data: {
                "test": "bar"
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

What am I missing or how do I have to send my data?

It's even not working like this:

```
{"tx_ext_bm[test]": "bar"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can no one provide a working example with jQuery Ajax in TYPO3 Backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no answer in any of the forums I've questioned this, so I ended up accessing the params the traditional way with `$_POST`.